# Merge dataframe in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have 3 dataframe:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['1a', '1b', '1c', '1d'], 'col2': ['2a','2b','2c','2d'],}, 
index=[[1,2,1,2],['a','a','b','b']])
df1.index.names = ['index1', 'index2']
df2=pd.DataFrame({'col3': ['3a','3b'], 'col4': ['4a','4b']}, index=[[1,2],['a','a']])
df2.index.names = ['index1', 'index2']
df3=pd.DataFrame({'col3': ['3c','3d'], 'col4': ['4c','4d']}, index=[[1,2],['b','b']])
df3.index.names = ['index1', 'index2']
```

What can I do to obtain (with operations as join, concat or merge I believe):

```
df5=pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['1a', '1b', '1c', '1d'], 'col2': ['2a','2b','2c','2d'], 
'col3': ['3a','3b', '3c', '3d'], 'col4': ['4a','4b', '4c', '4d']}, index=[[1,2,1,2], 
['a','a','b','b']])
df5.index.names = ['index1', 'index2']
```

It always creates me either a new column with the same or a different name and with good and NaN values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) - first by default `axis=0` and then by `axis=1`:

```
df5 = pd.concat([df1, pd.concat([df2, df3])], axis=1)
print (df5)
              col1 col2 col3 col4
index1 index2                    
1      a        1a   2a   3a   4a
2      a        1b   2b   3b   4b
1      b        1c   2c   3c   4c
2      b        1d   2d   3d   4d
```

General solution with list of DataFrames and [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) in list comprehension with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]

df5 = pd.concat([x.stack() for x in dfs]).unstack()
print (df5)
              col1 col2 col3 col4
index1 index2                    
1      a        1a   2a   3a   4a
       b        1c   2c   3c   4c
2      a        1b   2b   3b   4b
       b        1d   2d   3d   4d
```

Comment: rename_axis is likely not needed, this is probably a typo

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to do the same with df2,df3,...dfn?

Comment: @Wick - added solution to answer.

Comment: @Wick - Last solution not working?

Answer (score 1):

Use a double [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), once on the default `axis=0` for `df2`/`df3`, then on `axis=1` with `df1`:

```
df5 = pd.concat([df1, pd.concat([df2, df3])], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
              col1 col2 col3 col4
index1 index2                    
1      a        1a   2a   3a   4a
2      a        1b   2b   3b   4b
1      b        1c   2c   3c   4c
2      b        1d   2d   3d   4d
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to do the same with df2,df3,...dfn?

Comment: Yes, just put the DataFrames in the lists: `pd.concat([dfx, dfy, dfz, ...])`

Comment: ```c=[]
c.append(df2)
c.append(df3)
c.append(df3)
df5 = pd.concat([df1, pd.concat(c)], axis=1)```

gives me:
```InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects```

and ```df5 = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3], axis=1)``` gives me multiples columns with the same name