# Merge multiple dataframes pandas reindex error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to do a "merging" of dataframes as [Merge dataframe in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76062901/merge-dataframe-in-python/76062924?noredirect=1#comment134146415_76062924)

However it seems like the solution doesn't work for multiple dataframes:

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
ltick=['SOLB.BR', 'HOLN.SW', 'NOKIA.HE', 'ACA.PA']
end_date=max(df.index.get_level_values(0))
y_l=[]
for tick in sorted(ltick):
    y=yf.Ticker(tick).history(start='2002-04-22', end=end_date)[['Dividends', 'Stock 
Splits']]
    y['ISIN']=[my_dict2[tick]]*len(y)
    form = [ts.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for ts in y.index]
    y.index=form
    y.index.names = ['Date']
    y = y.set_index('ISIN', append=True)
    y_l.append(y)
df=yf.Ticker("SPY").history(start='2002-04-22', end=end_date)[['Dividends', 'Stock 
Splits']]
df = pd.concat([df, pd.concat(y_l)], axis=1)
```

gives me the error

```
pd.concat([df, pd.concat(y_l)], axis=1)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py:331, in deprecate_nonkeyword_arguments.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    325 if len(args) > num_allow_args:
    326     warnings.warn(
    327         msg.format(arguments=_format_argument_list(allow_args)),
    328         FutureWarning,
    329         stacklevel=find_stack_level(),
    330     )
--> 331 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py:381, in concat(objs, axis, join, ignore_index, keys, levels, names, verify_integrity, sort, copy)
    159 """
    160 Concatenate pandas objects along a particular axis.
    161 
   (...)
    366 1   3   4
    367 """
    368 op = _Concatenator(
    369     objs,
    370     axis=axis,
   (...)
    378     sort=sort,
    379 )
--> 381 return op.get_result()

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py:612, in _Concatenator.get_result(self)
    610         obj_labels = obj.axes[1 - ax]
    611         if not new_labels.equals(obj_labels):
--> 612             indexers[ax] = obj_labels.get_indexer(new_labels)
    614     mgrs_indexers.append((obj._mgr, indexers))
    616 new_data = concatenate_managers(
    617     mgrs_indexers, self.new_axes, concat_axis=self.bm_axis, copy=self.copy
    618 )

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3904, in Index.get_indexer(self, target, method, limit, tolerance)
   3901 self._check_indexing_method(method, limit, tolerance)
   3903 if not self._index_as_unique:
-> 3904     raise InvalidIndexError(self._requires_unique_msg)
   3906 if len(target) == 0:
   3907     return np.array([], dtype=np.intp)

InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

Do you know how can I fix that?

Comment: Don't you need to specify `axis=1` in this `pd.concat(y_l)` as well? also, would `df = pd.concat([df]+y_l, axis=1)` give the same result instead of nested concat?

Comment: Ben.T is right about concat. Also the error message "Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects" is telling you that some columns are repeating. Indeed 'Dividends', 'Stock Splits' are found in all dataframes. Try renaming them by adding a suffix. eg `y.columns = [col + '_' + tick for col in y.columns]`

Comment: in fact I want that these data goes in the same column if it fits with the indexs, there is no issue I believe